# Advantage of coherent path integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, many-body, second-quantization, coherent-states

I think(?) I am quite familiar with path integral over phase space, but not familiar with the coherent state path integral. What is the advantage of this coherent path integral besides the usual path integral over phase space?

In some context that I found online, it states, the coherent state path integral reduces Feynman's path integral (Does that mean coherent path integral is a much bigger concept than the usual Feynman's path integral over phase space?)

For a glimpse, the coherent path integral involves the Ladder operator which gives me clue about the issue regarding quantizations, or Hamiltonian formulations. But If one focuses only on computing some physical quantities like scattering amplitudes, It seems such Hamiltonian formulation does not powerful.

**What is the advantage of coherent path integral better than the usual path integral besides canonical quantization? and what makes coherent path integral useful (or meaningful) than the usual Fenyman's path integral formulation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest [Shankar's *Renormalization-group approach to interacting fermions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9307009) (originally [published in RMP](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.66.129)) as a crash course in the coherent state path integral. It is very readable. In a nutshell:

- this is how you do path integral in second quantization
- this is perhaps the only way to do it for fermions

**Remarks:**

- We mostly need the coherent state path integral for many-body problems. In one-particle context it is mostly useless (with some exceptions.)
- Interesting applications of coherent state path integral beyond physics include its applications to birth&death processes [in statistics](http://www.peliti.org/Publications/pathIntegrals.pdf) and [more specifically in population genetics](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0205321).